# grepl and paste to get a character vector where elements separated by commas

Tags: r, paste, grepl

I am trying to include a number of time dummies (eg `year.f1990`) that I generated into a command (`eba` from the ExtremeBounds package) which accepts vectors of the form `c("variable1","variable2","variable3") so strings separated by commas. I have trouble generating such a vector for my time dummies. Take:

```
Data <- data.frame(year.f1 = c(1,0), year.f2 = c(0,1))
```

so I want and element exactly like `c("year.f1","year.f2")`

I managed to get both `c("year.f1,year.f2")` and `c("year.f1" "year.f2")` with these two commands:

```
test1 <- paste(names(Data)[grepl("year.f",names(Data),fixed=TRUE)],collapse = ",")
test2 <- names(Data)[grepl("year.f",names(Data),fixed=TRUE)]
```

but these are both not quite what I need. The first one misses the quotation marks around the single elements, the second one misses the commas. I want the separation with commas AND each element framed by "...". Any help would be appreciated!

p.s.: From the comments below:

This:

```
variables <- c("var1","var2",test1,"var3")
```

should work like this:

```
variables <- c("var1","var2","year.f1","year.f2","var3")
```

Comment: Change `collapse` to `sep` like `paste(names(Data)[grepl("year.f",names(Data),fixed=TRUE)],sep = ",")`

Comment: `toString(names(Data)[which(Data!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]])`

Comment: `deparse(names(Data))`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answers! When I try the solutions of Pierre and akrun, they don't insert commas. I was also really surprised when the sep command inside paste did nothing. I think this is due to the fact that the grepl command is one argument inside paste so it would only insert commas between that output and any other element. Richards solution comes closer but what am I to do with these backslashes?

Comment: @PeterPan My code gives `"year.f1, year.f2"`, though I am not sure why `c(` should be there.  If you need quote for both (didn't see it earlier) `toString(dQuote(names(Data)))`

Comment: The backslashes aren't really there in real life :).  Check `cat(deparse(names(Data)))`

Comment: @akrun: the c(...) is not needed at all, I just thought thats what I get if I would assign a name to it: a string vector. Your solution works now though I'm not sure what to do about the double quotes.

Comment: @RichardScriven: Thats it, thanks! Sometimes I love real life... Do you want to make it an answer or is this so trivial that I should erase the question?

Comment: After reading your previous comment, I'm not sure you want this because without more code you won't be able to get what you want when you assign it.

Comment: Sorry, may be i misunderstood the question.  I thought you wanted double quote string pasted together.

Comment: I want to use it in a package (ExtremeBounds, eba) which needs this kind of vector as input of a list of variables. I want to include all year dummies this way. So if this vector is called "test", I want to be able to generate something like `variables <- c("var1","var2",test,"var3")` where `test` joins the vector in the same form. So the result would be `variables <- c("var1","var2","year.f1","year.f2","var3")`. Should I rephrase the question somehow?

Comment: Maybe you could expand the question to include what you plan to do with the result

Comment: Looks like you are not pasting the variables.

Comment: I rewrote the question. The variables change in different specification so I'm writing them out. If I create `test` manually, it works so the problem is really to get the right structure of that vector

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT "strings separated by commas" ... and despite being displayed with each element double-quoted, it doesn't actually have quotes in the characters in the internal representation. A `grep(..)` for the double quotes character would fail.

```
c("variable1","variable2","variable3")
```

It is a vector of 3 character values (stings if you wish but there are no commas in it.) The commas are not really in that value but are rather syntactic separators that the interpreter uses to construct a value for a vector. Staring with:

```
  Data <- data.frame(year.f1 = c(1,0), year.f2 = c(0,1))
```

The way to get a value that is the same as `c("year.f1","year.f2")` would simply be:

```
 names(Data)
```

If you started out with:

```
  variables <- c("var1","var2",test1,"var3")
```

Then this is what would return the desired result

```
test1 <- names(Data)
variables <- c("var1", "var2", test1, "var3")
```

The value: `c("year.f1, year.f2")` would not be particularly useful,. It could not be parsed correctly because of the missing double quotes flanking the (real) comma.

To solve the revised question this should satisfy:

```
hits <- names(Data)
variables <- c("var1", "var2", hits[grepl("year\\.f", hits)], "var3")
```

Comment: All that is clear and I tried to work with names() in my failed example. How can I get only those names which start with "year.f" into a character vector? I updated the heading along the lines suggested by you